# unable to open excel sheet in linux

Tags: linux, java, xls

I am not able to open excel file which is generated from java web application in Linux. The file is opening in Windows but not in Linux.

I am not using Open Office. I have two different applications deployed in two different was7 servers in same Linux machine. Both the applications generate excel output stream which I open in IE. When I am trying the same application in Windows environment both are working fine, but in Linux I can open and download xls files in one application but not in other. I am using application/vnd-ms... as mime type and POI jars to generated excel, no errors in my debug log or system errors.

Comment: Not enough information. Are you opening it with OpenOffice?

Comment: Are you trying to open the exact same file on different platforms, or are there distinct files generated per each platform? In the latter case, have you compared them?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using OpenOffice or Gnumeric on Linux to open the Excel file?

If not install one of those. Gnumeric is only an Excel replacement OpenOffice is a replacement for the entire Microsoft Office suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc).

On Ubuntu or any other Debian-based systems you can install open office by going to the terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install openoffice.org` or for gnumeric going to the terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install gnumeric`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to upload the file to Google Docs and try to open in there.  Google can't always convert the file, but if it can then you can view the spreadsheet from any other computer you log into your Google account from.

Other than that, you can use OpenOffice.org, LibreOffice (an OpenOffice fork) or another FOSS office suite or program which can open Excel files.